# Haskell strongly typed data bases

Tags: database, haskell, ysod

In the [yesod book on persistence](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent#persistent_integration_with_yesod), the following paragraph talks about "... store strongly typed Haskell data":

> Some Haskellers have attempted a more revolutionary route: creating
>   Haskell specific data stores that allow one to easily store any
>   strongly typed Haskell data. These options are great for certain use
>   cases, but they constrain one to the storage techniques provided by
>   the library and do not interface well with other languages.

I did a quick google search but it turned up sql related libraries on hackage. Also there is no hackage category "data base", only "data" which I don't want to search manually. Who are "those haskellers" and what are the currently developed haskell projects in this regard?

Comment: Maybe [ACID-state](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/acid-state)?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz that's an interesting project, but I was thinking more about data bases or solutions that offer reasonable performance to store numeric data. ACID seems more of a way to keep perstiance of an application. But also the paragraph above talks about "data stores", so a generic term.

Comment: [I've also found a more comprehensive list here](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Web/Databases_and_Persistence)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz that link sums it up. There is just acid-state and happstack-state that are non-sql-backward-compatible. The first seemst to be geared towards app-state persitance the second seems to be about web-framework persitance. There doesn't seem to be a haskell project that is a kind of a database (e.g., storing numeric values with good performance).

Comment: Its not really a database but it is a datastore - there also exists `dynamic-state` which can be made nice and typesafe using Lenses. Good for storing customizable data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bartek's comment pretty much answers the question (if you come up with a better one please write your answer):

According to hackage [Web/Databases and Persistence page](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Web/Databases_and_Persistence), there is [ACID-state](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/acid-state) and happstack-state.